# Looping through JSON in Javascript. Object in Object?

Tags: javascript, json

Looking to loop through JSON that comes back like this in javascript and access the 'line' and other variables.

```
{
"2":{"league":"MLB","matchnum":"2","site":"1","line":"-120","teamname":"COL"},
"1":{"league":"MLB","matchnum":"1","site":"2","line":"111","teamname":"SF"}
}
```

This appears to be the answer but I think the issue is i'm trying to access a value thats in an object in an object.

```
for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    var obj = json[i];

    console.log(obj.id);
}
```

Where I am going wrong here? Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: There's no `id` anywhere in the JSON. What is the expected result in the console?

Answer (score 1):

There's no `id` in the JSON provided. If you would like to display `1` and `2`, well you can do this way using `for ... in` loop. Otherwise you can access all the elements from the JavaScript Object this way too.

```js
var json = {
  "2": {
    "league": "MLB",
    "matchnum": "2",
    "site": "1",
    "line": "-120",
    "teamname": "COL"
  },
  "1": {
    "league": "MLB",
    "matchnum": "1",
    "site": "2",
    "line": "111",
    "teamname": "SF"
  }
};
for (var i in json) {
  var obj = json[i];
  console.log(i);
  console.log(obj.teamname);
}
```

Moreover, the main issue as pointed out by [Charlie Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1826354/charlie-martin) is that you are trying to call `.length` on an object, which gives you undesirable results, i.e., the `length` property of a JavaScript object is not at all defined.

Comment: The much larger issue than the missing id is that he is trying to call `.length` on an object, which is always `undefined`

Comment: @CharlieMartin I just updated the answer again...

Comment: @CharlieMartin Check the updated answer bro... Gave you credits as well.